# find blank cells in columns and replace them with 0, repeat for next row if next row has data

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel userform to input the data. I want for Columns C2:F2, if the user has not inputted any number in it, excel should convert these blanks into 0. And I want it to repeat for the next row when the data for next row is inputted. I tried some simple coding but it didn't work.

```
Public Sub BlankCells()



Dim rng As Range

rng = Range("C2:C1000", "D2:D1000", "E2:E1000", "F2:F1000")
 
 For Each cell In rng
 
If cell = "" Then cell.Value = "0"

Next cell

Find


End Sub
```

It works if use coding for single row only i.e. "C2:F2", but i want it repeat for the next rows as well when the next row gets the data.

Comment: Don't iterate through the cells after the fact, have whatever it is you're using to write the userform data convert the blanks to 0's before you paste them.

Comment: `Set rng = Range("C2:F1000")` will be the quick fix I suppose, but not the cleanest way to run through an array. Note, you implicitly refer to the currently active worksheet too.

Comment: Maybe `Range("C2:F1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0`?

Comment: @RyanWildry, I was just writing that down. Much smoother than looping through all cells.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a variable for sheet or range, you need to use the `Set` keyword like this:

```
Set rng = Range("C2:F1000")
```

If you'd like to refer to [multiple ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-multiple-ranges), you can add all the ranges as one comma separated string